# Regexr expression doesn't work in groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm looking to get 4 digits that will be surrounded by spaces.
e.g. foo 2420 blah
using regexr i got this pattern \b\d{4}\b
i translated this to groovy as

```
def courseNum = course.text =~ $/\b\d{4}\b/$
System.out.print(courseNum.group())
```

this is returning no matches even though I am positive the string does contain 4 digits by themselves.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `.group()` you are using causes the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found` exception. You just need to access the match value via the 0th index, `courseNum[0]`.

Also, I would use a simple slashy string here, since it is enough and convenient enough to define a regular  expression.

```
def text = "New 7234 pcs"
def courseNum = text =~ /\b\d{4}\b/
print(courseNum[0])
```

See [this Groovy demo](http://ideone.com/VpgRiT)

However, since you want to get *4 digits that will be **surrounded by spaces***, you do not have to rely on `\b` word boundaries, use lookarounds to require string start/end or whitespace around the 4 digits:

```
/(?<!\S)\d{4}(?!\S)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/96ox0m/1).

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to do this is with the `findAll(regex)` method.

```
​def text = "CSE 2443, MATH 5003"
text.findAll(/\b\d{4}\b/).each {
    println it
}
```

Resulting in (`[2443, 5003]`)

```
2443
5003
```

Even if it doesn't match, it will not error like your current instantiation. Find all basically returns all matches as an array list and is therefore safer.